# I am using Case for SQL select query and want to calculate price dynamically

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, case, query-builder

**My Controller code**

```php
$nicepay_commission = Configure::read('nicepay_commission');
$paypal_commission = Configure::read('paypal_commission');
 
$getQuery = $this->OrderProduct
    ->find('all', [
        'contain' => [
            'Orders' => ['PaymentMethods'],
            'Products' => ['ProductType']
        ]
    ])
   ->distinct('Products.id')
   ->select([
        'product_name' => 'MAX(Products.product_name)',
        'count' => 'SUM(OrderProduct.qty)', 
        'actual_rate' => 'SUM(OrderProduct.actual_rate)',
        'revenue_based_actual_rate' => '(
            SUM(
                CASE
                WHEN PaymentMethods.payment_gateway = \'nicepay\'
                THEN (OrderProduct.actual_rate-((OrderProduct.actual_rate*"'.$nicepay_commission.'")/100))
                WHEN PaymentMethods.payment_gateway = \'paypal\'
                THEN (OrderProduct.actual_rate-((OrderProduct.actual_rate*"'.$paypal_commission.'")/100))
                ELSE (OrderProduct.actual_rate)
                END
            )
        )'
   ])
   ->where($conditions);
```

But there is some error occurring I couldn't find how to manage this.

**My error log looks like**

> 2020-08-20 07:56:56 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name '2'.

**If I staticly use the values then there is no error**

```php
$getQuery = $this->OrderProduct
    ->find('all', [
        'contain' => [
            'Orders' => ['PaymentMethods'],
            'Products' => ['ProductType']
        ]
    ])
    ->distinct('Products.id')
    ->select([
        'product_name' => 'MAX(Products.product_name)',
        'count' => 'SUM(OrderProduct.qty)',
        'actual_rate' => 'SUM(OrderProduct.actual_rate)',
        'revenue_based_actual_rate' => '(
            SUM(
                CASE
                WHEN PaymentMethods.payment_gateway = \'nicepay\'
                THEN (OrderProduct.actual_rate-((OrderProduct.actual_rate*2)/100))
                WHEN PaymentMethods.payment_gateway = \'paypal\'
                THEN (OrderProduct.actual_rate-((OrderProduct.actual_rate*1)/100))
                ELSE (OrderProduct.actual_rate)
                END
            )
        )'
    ])
    ->where($conditions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, *never* insert date into SQL snippets directly if it can be avoided, even if you think that they might stem from a secure source!

That being said, look at the generated SQL query (if you're not already using [**Debug Kit**](https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/3/en/index.html), you should install it), you are enclosing the values in double quotes, ie the generated SQL will look like:

```sql
OrderProduct.actual_rate * "2"
```

which in ISO SQL means `2` is going to be used  as an identifier.

Removing the quotes will fix the problem, but you're still injecting dynamic data into an SQL string, which should be avoided if possible, so you should go a step further and bind the values instead, in order to reduce the chances of creating SQL injection vulnerabilities:

```php
// ...
->select([
    'product_name' => 'MAX(Products.product_name)',
    'count' => 'SUM(OrderProduct.qty)', 
    'actual_rate' => 'SUM(OrderProduct.actual_rate)',
    'revenue_based_actual_rate' => '(
        SUM(
            CASE
            WHEN PaymentMethods.payment_gateway = \'nicepay\'
            THEN (OrderProduct.actual_rate-((OrderProduct.actual_rate * :nicepayCommission)/100))
            WHEN PaymentMethods.payment_gateway = \'paypal\'
            THEN (OrderProduct.actual_rate-((OrderProduct.actual_rate * :paypalCommission)/100))
            ELSE (OrderProduct.actual_rate)
            END
        )
    )'
])
->bind(':nicepayCommission', $nicepay_commission, 'integer')
->bind(':paypalCommission', $paypal_commission, 'integer')
// ...
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > SQL Injection Prevention](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#sql-injection-prevention)**

Comment: I am using bind as you write but still there is an error in log-  "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens". How can this be solve?

Comment: @PriyankaHazra That shouldn't happen with the example I've shown, it has exactly 2 placeholders and binds to both of them, so there should be no mismatch. Make sure that you have no typos, and debug your query to figure where the problem might be (`debug($query)`, check the `sql` and `params` keys).